# Method for create a copy of List<T>

Tags: java, array, generics, casting

I created a method to return a copy of `List<T>`, basically I convert the `List<T>` into an array `T[]`, then perform the copy with the `arrayCopy(T[])` method and back convert again in `List<T>`.

I want to know if the code will be run successfully in different scenarios and it is good in performance or is there a way to do it better.

```
public static <T> List<T> getCopyOfList(List<T> list) {
    return Arrays.asList((T[]) arrayCopy(list.toArray()));
}

public static <T> T[] arrayCopy(final T[] original) {
    return Arrays.copyOf(original, original.length);
}
```

Comment: You're not creating a copy of a List. You're creating a new list with the same elements as the original list. The difference is important as "a copy" would imply that the result is a copy of the original, sharing the same object type and the elements. As such this helper method is a bit useless as the caller can not choose the correct list implementation for their use case. So I ask the same question as Eric Stein: why not just use the copy constructor? Can you elaborate on why you need these methods?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Given that `arrayCopy` has exactly one line, it's not clear that there's much value in having it extracted as a method.

`toArray()` is [documented](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/List.html#toArray()) to return a safe array, so there is no need to copy it.

`getCopyOfList` returns a fixed-length list without documenting that fact. Clients may be surprised that optional `List` methods such as `add()` and `remove()` are not supported.

Why wouldn't clients prefer to use the copy constructors available on `LinkedList` and `ArrayList`? Those would allow clients to control the type of List they're working with, and the call is part of the public API.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, I will adapt my implementation.

Answer (score 2):

Don't create Rube Goldberg machines. There is an easier way to accomplish what you want:

```
public static <T> List<T> getCopyOfList(List<T> list) {
    
    return new ArrayList<T>(list);
    
}
```